# For loop in PostgreSQL to call API

Tags: sql, postgresql

With a table

```
SELECT * FROM tmp_re_11542 ;
 account_id_column | first_name | last_name
-------------------|------------|----------
5432
```

I wonder how I can implement the **for loop** in the case where I have to run a query `(api.get_data_on_account_id())` and save results in the same table (below is pseudo code)

```
For each account_id_column in tmp_table do:
  INSERT INTO tmp_table(first_name, last_name) 
    SELECT first_name,last_name api.get_data_on_account_id(account_id_column, NULL,'constant_str');
```

Comment: Would recommend starting here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Answer (score 2):

You should use INSERT INTO SELECT query instead of for loop for this operation as following:-

```
INSERT INTO tmp_table (first_name, last_name)
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM tmp_re_11542;
```

Comment: . . I'm upvoting, but the OP provided a bit more information, so perhaps you should update the query.